# Solving this specific series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can somebody help me prove this equality? I tried factoring out $\left(\frac{a}{1+a}\right)$ to use geometric series formula but that k term gives me a hard time. Thanks in advance.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k \left(\frac{a}{1+a}\right)^k =a(1+a) $$ where $a$ is positive and$\left(\frac{a}{1+a}\right)$ < 1.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^k$ for $|z|<1$? Just set $z=\frac{a}{1+a}$ in that formula if you do.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$. Now, differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ to get $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. Now put $x=\dfrac{a}{1+a}$

Comment: you have a mistake; $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

Comment: @HarveyMudd: Thanks. Will correct.